# Checked luggage & terminating trip during layover

Tags: air-travel, luggage, layovers, passenger-rights, hidden-city-ticketing

I have a Canada bound Delta flight next month with a layover in New York where I plan to abandon the trip (the flight to Canada was cheaper than to USA, hidden city ticketing).

Now I know all international flights stopping over in the USA requires passengers to deplane, pass through immigration and customs with their bags and then check in to their local connecting flight so I should  have no problem retrieving my checked bags.

My question is for other countries where one doesn’t get access to checked bags during international layovers, are the airlines mandated to return passengers luggage to me at the location where a passenger decides to abandon the remaining legs of the trip? Or airlines have the right to deliver it to the final purported destination and it’s up to the passengers to figure out how to retrieve it?

Comment: I’m pretty sure this is a duplicate and the question was asked (again) quite recently.

Comment: any luck @jcaron?